# ffmpeg lossless conversion webm to mp4 produces file not visibile by winmediaplayer

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, lossless-compression

I have some webms (around 3 mb each) and I need to transform them in mp4, possibly using an RGB profile.
I need a true lossless conversion because I need to extract rgb info from the files to do further analysis.

On windows 10, I start ffmpeg from command line with

```
-crf 0 -preset veryslow -c:v libx264rgb
```

It works and produces mp4 with very good quality and a large dimension (3mb --> 50mb).
However, something is not right, this mp4s are only visible in VLC, windows media player report a generic error (no error code) that cannot play the file.
I got similar generic errors when processing these file in other applications too. Therefore, I suppose something went wrong with the conversion.

Can someone provide some insight on this?

If not, can someone suggest a true lossless conversion from webm to mp4, possibly with an RGB profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose something went wrong with the conversion.

Nothing went wrong with the conversion. Playback support for lossless H.264 RGB is limited.

> can someone suggest a true lossless conversion from webm to mp4, possibly with an RGB profile? (That will play in WMP).

Other than H.264 which you already tried your choices are limited. You could try:

- Lossless HEVC (libx265), but I doubt that would play in WMP.

  ```
    ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 output.mp4
  ```
- PNG in MP4. Not sure if that will play in WMP.

  ```
    ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:v png output.mp4
  ```